# Eclipse com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage$Builder can not be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse

Java editor inside Eclipse IDE showed the below error message suddenly:

> The type com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage$Builder cannot be
>   resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Code auto-completion does not work any more. I restart Eclipse IDE, but nothing change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type `Builder` inside class `com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage` is not found.

(A package named `com.google.protobuf` has class `GeneratedMessage`, and class `Builder` inside class `GeneratedMessage`. This case called inner class).

You miss file JAR what include `com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage$Builder` in class-path.

Comment: I did not use this class directly. I use gradle build. what is the jar? thanks

Comment: You are missing this class: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage.Builder  try to check your SDK, or need declare dependency to Gradle build config.

Answer (score 1):

Add this dependency to your pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
    <artifactId>grpc-protobuf</artifactId>
    <version>1.16.1</version>
</dependency>
```